# How long must an insurer retain records of opt-outs for, in Canada?

Tags: discussion

Why did Ganesh S delete close [How long must an insurer retain records of opt-outs for, in Canada?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119377/44213)

> as off-topic because it's a very specific question of law with only peripheral relevant to personal finance?

This question undeniably is about insurance, not law. It's not "very specific" – it assists anyone who opts out of any insurance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a blurry line for whether legal questions are on-topic, discussed [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/should-questions-about-legal-matters-be-on-topic). Users of the site can vote to re-open if they think the question is ok, I won't re-close.

Note that questions about insurance are not necessarily on-topic either.